# How to implement the AAD B2C feature in angular2 application using typescript?

Tags: angular, azure, typescript, azure-ad-b2c

I developed web application using angular2 and typescript. But one of my client asked the feature as Azure B2C, implement in angular2 application for logging customers in to this application instead of Oauth.

For that I did the simple example using below link to implement Azure B2C concept for .NET Web app.

[Azure AD B2C: Build a .NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet)

The .Net web application worked fine but I want to implement the same feature in angular2 application using typescript.

Can you please tell me how to implement the azure B2C feature in angular2 application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there is *no official* module / library available to use AAD B2C in a SPA. Mostlikely the new library MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) will support AAD B2C anytime in the future.

Currently you have to use **adal.js** and modify it yourself to work with AAD B2C. You probably want to use the implicit flow in order to do this because it doesn't reveal the client secret to the clients. Here is a good overview about [AAD B2C for Single-Page Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa).

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer I think there is no predefined library available for Azure B2C feature. Can I expect when the library available in the azure market. And tell me right now any one didn't implement this feature in any angular 2 application using typescript is it correct?

Comment: I am sure someone is using AAD B2C within his Angular2 typescript project. But there is no *official* library available yet. Hope we get one soon.

Comment: The above GitHub sample completely java script but I am not much familiar in java script. and I want same java script code in typescript because right now I am using typescript to develop angular 2 web application.

Comment: This is probably the best articel you get about AAD B2C for SPA at the moment. There is no typescript equivalent available. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks, tell me whether it is possible or not to implement B2C feature in angular2 application using typescript not an java script.

Comment: You can do anything with typescript what you can do with javascript since you can invoke javascript within ts. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Can you please post simple typescript sample with Azure B2C feature.

Comment: No, I have no typescript sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142131/discussion-between-pradeep-and-martin-brandl).